# Memory Usage with Chrome on El-Capitan

Tags: macos, google-chrome

This is from my log

Apr 19 01:05:48 Vijays-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: Google Chrome[263] triggered unnest of range 0x7fff90600000->0x7fff90800000 of DYLD shared region in VM map 0xba2f67bd2e26049b. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.

Does anybody has any idea regarding the same?

Comment: are you using el capitan on virtual machine

Comment: Nope @NirpendraPatel